# Laravel chat message relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-9

I want to integrate a chat functionality to my application. Therefore, I created a Message model with the attributes message, sender and receiver. I don't see the point of creating a table for chats, as there would be no attributes besides the things given by the message model. However, having a model and a resource for chats would be handy. So, for me a chat is basically all messages between two users.
How can I create a chat model without its own database table that groups messages of individual users and how could the relationship to the users model be implemented to return all chats a user is part of?

```
class Message extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    use SoftDeletes;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'message',
        'sender_id',
        'receiver_id'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [];

    /**
     * Get the user who sent this message
     */
    public function sender() {
        $this->hasOne(User::class, 'sender_id');
    }

    /**
     * Get the user who received this message
     */
    public function receiver() {
        $this->hasOne(User::class, 'receiver_id');
    }

    /**
     * Get the chat
     */
    public function chat() {
        $this->belongsTo(Chat::class);
    }
}
```

and the Migration

```
return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('messages', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->text('message');
            $table->foreignId('sender_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->foreignId('receiver_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('messages');
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can actually create a table named `Conversation` to hold the two users who actually chatting.

It doesn't matter much who is the sender and receiver, it's just holding the two users' value and whoever chatted first will be the `sender_id`.

A structure like this

```
conversation:
 sender_id,
 receiver_id

message: 
 content,
 conversation_id,
 sender_id
```

which holds the sender and receiver will be flexible enough for your message model to join the relationship and get the expected value.